# google map will output inaccurate coordinate in short range

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm using google maps to store some locations coordinate in my database by marker drag and drop

here is how i do it :

on the api :

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "dragend", function(event) {
            updatePosition(event);
        });
```

here is the function

```
    function updatePosition(evt){

    console.log(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3)+' # '+evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3));

    var lt =  evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) ;
    var lg =  evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) ;

    // posting to database  

    }
```

it works almost fine but  it is very inaccurate in close range

the first picture as you can see will output `40.714 # -74.009`

[image]

the second picture .. on the other side of street also will output `40.714 # -74.009`

[image]

i have to go all the way down here , to see it change

[image]

so if i load map using `40.714 , -74.009` trying to show the `spa` it could show `bus stop` or `hairstyle` across street !

is there anyway to get the exact location even for the short range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 decimal places equates to approx 100 meters [**See**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).For your purpose you will need 6 decimal places.

```
function updatePosition(evt){

    console.log(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)+' # '+evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

    var lt =  evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) ;
    var lg =  evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6) ;

    // posting to database  

    }
```